# All Posts Linking to Author Posts directly

Tags: posts, links, author, profiles

I want to do "All Posts" hyperlinked to Author-Link so when user clicked All posts then user will be directed to Author's all posts, instead of "All Posts of: Author-Link"

I don't want repeatation of name.

My site is www.engineeringfailurerecord.com

Help please, tell me where to code and what to code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to edit your theme files. You need to search each files looking for something along the lines of

```
<p>All Posts of: <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></p>
```

and just change that to

```
<p><a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID')); ?>">All Posts</a></p>
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you post has answered your question, please mark the question as answered to help the rest of the community and me.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: On the left side of the answer, is a helpful or unhelpful rating (up and down arrows). Below that should be a checkmark visible only to the author of the question. Mark the checkmark for the question that solved your question.